# Foreign key mapping in RestKit does not work for nested relationships

Tags: restkit

Given 3 entity types: `User` (a conversation participant), `Chat` (a text conversation between 2 `User`s),  and `VideoCall` (always tied to a `Chat`, where one of the users is a Caller).

If an API endpoint returns a `VideoCall` object, foreign key mapping to `Chat` and `User` works fine.

```
<DRVideoCall: 0x16f27f00> (entity: DRVideoCall; id: 0x182a1c90 <x-coredata://07D2A791-2CE9-46B1-8060-E288EC2ED4A4/DRVideoCall/p9> ; data: {
    caller = "0x16fbbff0 <x-coredata://07D2A791-2CE9-46B1-8060-E288EC2ED4A4/DRDoctor/p1>";
    callerId = 307;
    chat = "0x1826dca0 <x-coredata://07D2A791-2CE9-46B1-8060-E288EC2ED4A4/DRChat/p185>";
    chatId = 2748;
    state = calling;
```

})

But if it's nested into another mapping as a relationship, it does not, `chat` and `caller` properties are `nil`.

```
<DRVideoCall: 0x191bebb0> (entity: DRVideoCall; id: 0x1918b3d0 <x-coredata:///DRVideoCall/t24460E4B-9B6B-43F3-9981-62FDE53BFD5919> ; data: {
    caller = nil;
    callerId = 307;
    chat = nil;
    chatId = 2761;
    state = calling;
```

})

Is it possible with RestKit to make foreign key relationships work for nested objects?

Event mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *eventMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DREvent"
                                                    inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"type" : @"type" }];

RKRelationshipMapping *eventCallMapping =
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"call"
                                            toKeyPath:@"call"
                                          withMapping:[DRVideoCall mappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore]];

[eventMapping addPropertyMapping:eventCallMapping];
```

Video Call Mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *videoMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DRVideoCall"
                                  inManagedObjectStore:store];

[videoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"calling_user_id" : @"callerId",
                                                    @"chat_id" : @"chatId" }];

[videoMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"chat" connectedBy:@{ @"chatId" : @"chatId" }];
[videoMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"caller" connectedBy:@{ @"callerId" : @"userId" }];
```

*UPD:* Here's what `VideoCall` JSON looks like

```
{ 
  "chat_id":2748,
  "calling_user_id":307,
  "state":"calling",
  "session_id":"...",
  "token":"..."
}
```

And `Event` JSON:

```
{
    "call":{
        "calling_user_id":307,
        "chat_id":274,
        "session_id" = "...",
        "state":"calling",
        "token":"..."
    },
    "type":"call"
}
```

Comment: You generally use a nested mapping in this case, not foreign. You need to show the JSON.

Comment: @Wain added json examples for Chat and VideoCall

Comment: So you shouldn't also use a foreign key mapping when that mapping is nested (particularly if the foreign id is actually in the JSON). Are your relationships in the model bi-directional? The code looks generally ok & like the connection should be made.

Comment: If you notice, I've introduced another object type - `Event` that also includes `VideoCall` as a property. `Chat` turned out to be ok, just used the wrong property name. But in case of `Event`, there's no way to resolve the relationship to `Chat` and `User`, other than foreign key. Also the difference is that `Event` is mapped manually using `RKMapperOperation`, opposed to `RKObjectManager` requests used for `VideoCall` and `Chat`. Could it affect the foreign key behavior? @Wain

Comment: If you use a mapper operation explicitly then you need to be sure to set the cache on that operation so it can find foreign items (and prevent duplicates)

Comment: So, RK does not query the persistent storage directly when making a FK connection, rather it uses it's own cache? Then it starts to make sense. Thanks @Wain, I'll try to check it out!

Comment: The cache manages the query (if required)